# Extract initial character from field in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with this record

```
Title             Name
Rumah Sakit       Puri Medika
```

I want to extract initial character from each field so it will display "RSPM"

Thanks

Comment: You wanna do it withing the db? You shall have to create a func there. I am not sure MS-Access supports func or not.

Comment: Access does allow you to use user defined functions within your SQL statements. Just create the function in a code module using the Public statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Left([Title], 1) & 
Mid([Title], InStr([Title]," ") + 1, 1) & 
Left([Name], 1) & 
Mid([Name], InStr([Name]," ") +1, 1)
```